# How to adjust edittext's drawableright icon and text are in same line using xamarin

Tags: xamarin

[Please find the image  at below link that shows the edittext with icon and text that are not in same line horizontally. Here the text is little bit above to the icon.](https://app.box.com/s/ulq6mpl9thulr1lwdu03zf5eierffjdw)

-- Xaml code --

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="arabic text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/Username_icon"
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"/>
```

This edittext am using for arabic text. And here am trying to make drawableright icon and entered text to be in same line horizontally. Am not able to solve this. So please help me in this. Thank U.

Comment: Try use    `android:drawablePadding="10dp"`

Comment: sorry, its not adjusting. tried with drawablePadding value as 10dp and 20dp also

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
```

Comment: Already this same property applied but not adjusted. So, i have done this by using relative layout. Thank you